# Is the balanced 2P2N-4SAT problem NP-complete?

Tags: complexity-theory

Given a 4SAT instance such that:

1. Each clause has 2 negative and 2 positive literals. Thus, the clause is 'balanced'.
2. Each literal occurs exactly 2 times.

Is this instance of 4SAT NP-complete?

I am aware that the 2P2N-4SAT problem is NP-complete ([Proving 2P2N SAT is NP-Complete](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/21873/proving-2p2n-sat-is-np-complete)), but is the balanced cases also NP-Complete?

Comment: Do all literals in a clause refer to different variables?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus sorry for the late reply. all literals in each clause belong to different variables.

Comment: Every such instance is satisfiable.